# does catch statement in promise catch nested errors

Tags: javascript, promise

I wonder about situation when we must do an async task and the next one later:

```
promise1.then(() => {
    promise2.then(...).catch((err) => console.error(err));
})
.catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Will catch statement from promise1 catch error in promise2? If yes we can simple cut it to:

```
promise1.then(() => {
    promise2.then(...);
})
.catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Does it work?

Comment: It would work if you returned the promise created by `promise2.then()` (which would be the right way to do it)

Comment: Nope, it won't catch errors from a completely unrelated promise, but you can return the inner promise to the outer, and it would catch errors.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me one more thing? I don't want to make new post. If I would like to do the same thing in catch and then statement like this: `promise.then(() => console.log('same')).catch(() => console.log('same'));` Can I cut it in some way to not repeat?

Comment: No such thing as finally in native promises. Although some Promise libraries like bluebird support this.

Comment: @Stwosch Just do `promise.catch(err => null).then(promiseResultOrNull => console.log('same');`